# Can't read POST value from form in php send by jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send data from the ajax form and receive POST using php.
error on page:

Notice: Undefined index: numer in C:\xampp\htdocs\testajax\dalej.php on line 2.

**script for loading pages in index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var info = {
            content: "formularz"
        }
            loadContent('formularz');

            $('body').on('click', '.btn',function(e) {


                var content = $(this).data('content');

                if(info.content != content) {
                    loadContent(content);
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        function loadContent(content) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'loader.php',
                    type: 'post',

                    data: { Content : content },
                    success: function(response){

                        $('#content').html(response);
                        info.content = content;

                    }
                    });
        }
</script>
```

**loader.php**

```
?php
    $CONTENT = $_POST['Content'];


    if($CONTENT == 'formularz'){
        require_once('formularz.php');
    } else if($CONTENT == 'dalej') {
        require_once('dalej.php');
    }
?>
```

**script in formularz.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#newForm').on('submit', function(e){

                            e.preventDefault();
                            var numer = $('#number').val();
                            $.ajax({

                            type:"POST",  // <--- Should be post
                            data:{numer: numer},
                            url:'dalej.php'
                            });
                        });
    });
</script>
```

**trying to read POST in this page dalej.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['numer'])){
        echo $_POST['numer'];
    }

var_dump($_POST);
 ?>
```

Its look like ajax send POST values but php cant read it.:

[Firefox debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5nl.jpg)

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

showing this: array(1) { ["Content"]=> string(5) "dalej" }

Trying a lot o things like **Jquery Form plugin**, or change **$.ajax** to **$.post** with different values but result is always the same... I using Xampp 3.2.2 . Sory for my english and thanks you for help me with this problem :)

Comment: your error and file don't match up - according to your file you are checking isset($_POST['numer']) on line 2 - this wouldn't throw the error you're seeing. please check your files and edit your question.

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on external sites. Please edit your question accordingly. [ask]

Comment: Try to debug the javascript code in the browser - if you dont know read how to do that - try to put breakpoint in the beggining of javascript function and see how it goes during the declaration and on run. Also what I personally do when debugging AJAX is that Im doing alert("dumb_text") during different steps to see if the function is moving forward. Write back what you were able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Either change:

`<select  name="numer" id="numer" >`

To:

`<select  name="numer" id="number" >`

**Or**:

`var numer = $('#number').val();`

To:

`var numer = $('#numer').val();`

Comment: You should check regularly if your variable(/object/array) contains data because you will get this error if it doesn't. You can do this by using for example: `console.log($('#numer').val());` in JS.

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment wrong, you should change the element's `id` **OR** the selector's `id`, they should all be the same.